# Automatic Login Facebook PHP SDK as in Wordpress Easy Instagram Plugiin

Tags: wordpress, plugins, facebook-php-sdk

I am creating a wordpress plugin for admin. In which admin can show his selected photos from facebook album on front end.

App id and secret key are storing in db.

Login also working and it fetches the login user albums etc etc.

and Logout also working. But when on the site if some one has logged-in in my plugin then from any system it must show the login details.

What currently its doing is that to login to facebook, which i don't want.

The method i want in my plugin is same as its in wordpress easy instagram plugin, where in the site if the user logged in then it will always show the login credentials what happening in this instagram plugin is that is stores the access token in wp options table. if we delete the value for that option then it will specify in the back end to login.

I want same process in my plugin too.

Auto login process. (one time login)

Anyone knows how to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Just for clarification : So the issue is that, even though you are logged in to Facebook in the browser, had already once the login where the user "approves" for permissions, the plugin keeps ask over and over again to login and approve again ?

Comment: yes you are right..Have you checked the wordpress easy instagram plugin from dashboard.?? It not ask the login details once you are logged in. If you delete cookies or cache then also it will ask for logout from the wordpress dashboard. the same thing i want in my custom facebook plugin